# Modify a string literal in ELF x86_64 file

Tags: linux, elf

I have a ELF x86_64 (basically an executable file) and I'd like to replace a string literal within the file (without corrupting the executable file however)... and I should do that programmatically using a Linux bash/sh script...

Which is the simplest approach?

I've read somewhere that `sed` could be used (like on a regular text file) but there is the limitation that the new string must not be longer than the old one and must be zero-terminated... what if I'd like to replace with a longer string?

Thanks.

Comment: If you replace it with a longer string you'll be overwriting either data or code in the executable. If you're lucky, you'll get an immediate core dump when you run the program.

Comment: That's why I am asking the question... :) I mean: which is the simplest way for, let me say, disassemble the ELF, replace the string and re-assemble the ELF?

Comment: I would imagine similar problems if replacing with a shorter string too.

Comment: You might try `objdump -Mintel -d /path/to/binary` to get the assembly code. Replacing a string with a shorter string works as long as you pad the string with null bytes to match the original length.

Answer (score 1):

This will pad a shorter replacement with NULs and truncate a longer replacement, preventing you from accidentally corrupting the file.

If you *really* need to replace it with a longer string, there's no other way than to recompile (or use some ad-hoc hackery like hijacking another longer string from the file and changing all the references to the old string to point there). ELF files are not a kind of archives likes android apks.

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/PATTERN/substr q{REPLACEMENT}."\0"x length$&,0,length$&/e or die "pattern not found"' -i file
```

Change `PATTERN` and `REPLACEMENT` to whatever you need. Take care not to match NULs (`\0`) in `PATTERN`.

That could probably be made simpler.

Example:

```
$ cp /bin/sh /tmp/sh
$ /tmp/sh -c 'exec 7</tmp/jeg'
/tmp/sh: 1: cannot open /tmp/jeg: No such file
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/No such file/substr q{BLA BLA WHATEVER}."\0"x length($&),0,length$&/e' -i /tmp/sh
$ /tmp/sh -c 'exec 7</tmp/jeg'
/tmp/sh: 1: cannot open /tmp/jeg: BLA BLA WHAT
```

Comment: How do you keep from corrupting the binary when you replace with a longer string?

Comment: That's supposed to truncate the replacement. Tell me if you want a version which dies if the replacement is longer.

Comment: That was the original question.

Comment: You don't get it, do you? That does NOT corrupt the file. I'll add an example.

Comment: And your example replaced the string with another the same length. Read the last line of the post where he asked a question. Try changing your perl code so that the length of the replacement string is used.

Comment: If the replacement is shorter, the resulting string will be shorter. You still don't have a point.

Comment: Read the post. He wants the replacement string to be longer.

Comment: For that she or he will have to recompile.