# How can I modify the strings of a binary file?

Tags: binary

When I use `strings filename`, it lists all strings in a binary file. And now, I want to modify the strings that listed. But, how?

Comment: Do you just want to overtype one or more of the strings that are present, or do you want to replace a shorter string with a longer one?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/673242/325065

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CLI: Editing binary strings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450262/cli-editing-binary-strings)

Comment: I want to replace the strings in a binary file. For example: replace `abc` with `xyz` in my program. So, my program will print `xyz` instead of `abc`.

Comment: You said that already. But you haven't answered the question I asked

Answer (score 4):

If you replace a string with a string with the same length, you can edit a binary file with `sed`, and it will work in the context that you describe in the question and your comment.

I do it with iso files of Linux operating systems to make a persistent live drive by replacing `'quiet splash'` with `'persistent  '` (12 characters) in the grub menuentry. (See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10) and scroll down to 'Manual method' in my answer.)

First check with `strings` that the string you want to replace does not appear somewhere, that should not be modified (some binary sequence, that happens to contain that string), and then run for example

```
< original-file sed 's/abc/xyz/g' > modified-file
```

Comment: How can I replace with a non-same length string?

Comment: In general you can do it (for example with `sed 's/abc/wxyz/g'`), and it may or may not work depending on the kind of binary file that you modify. For example, an iso file with Linux will probably be corrupted. A program file will probably also be corrupted. Some kind of data file might still work, depending on how it is used.

Comment: I tried the same length string in my program, and it worked. But it's doesn't works when I try the non-same length string.

Comment: If you change the length of a string without "padding" it to the same length you will inevitably destroy a executable file (that is not built from text, as bash or python scripts). Pad with space (SPC) characters or NUL will often work.

Comment: @Arian, *If your program is a compiled program, you should modify the source code, compile and link it in order to modify it.* If it is an interpreted program (as the examples bash or python scripts by Hannu), then you can modify it freely directly in the program code, because the source code is the executable program.

Comment: My program is a compiled program, and it was just an example. Actually, I want to change the strings in closed-source programs, like Discord.

Comment: @Arian, With closed source programs you can only replace strings with strings of the same length, but as described in my example in the answer and in the comment by Hannu, you can replace a string with a shorter string plus blanks (padding). - Some programs may have a built-in check (using a checksum), that will stop them from working, if you change some strings.